# How to set startup page for a spcific folder only?

Tags: c#-4.0, web-config, asp.net-4.0

Below is my web application i have published...

my root application(http://test.smt.com)

also my root application contains a virtual dir (http://test.smt.com/console)

```
Root

  Folder 1(with 1.config)
  Folder 2(with 2.config)
  Folder 3(with 3.config)
  Folder 4(with 4.config) // I've created this directory as virtual dir

root.config
```

Now the issue i'm getting is, directory was listing when i enter http://test.smt.com/console

can we setup a start up for this particular page Folder? how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka!

open your IIS and Right click on the Folder, & set the start up page and enjoy!!!